# C "double to num" conversion code: why is it written like this?

Tags: c, double, type-conversion, low-level

I don't understand how the following C conversion functions work (and why they're written this way); I'm fairly certain that the original author knew what he was doing:

```
typedef union TValue {
  uint64_t u64;
  double n;
  struct {
    uint32_t lo;    /* Lower 32 bits of number. */
    uint32_t hi;    /* Upper 32 bits of number. */
  } u32;
  [...]
} TValue;


static int32_t num2bit(double n)
{
  TValue o;
  o.n = n + 6755399441055744.0;  /* 2^52 + 2^51 */
  return (int32_t)o.u32.lo;
}

static uint64_t num2u64(double n)
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  if (n >= 9223372036854775808.0)  /* They think it's a feature. */
    return (uint64_t)(int64_t)(n - 18446744073709551616.0);
  else
#endif
  return (uint64_t)n;
}
```

- Does num2bit actually just cast a `double` into `int32_t`? Why the addition? Why write it like this?
- What is this "feature" that is alluded to in num2u64? (I believe _MSC_VER means it's the code-path for Microsofts C compiler).

Note that those functions are not *always* used (depending on CPU architecture), this is for little-endian (I resolved some preprocessor macros to simplify).

Links to online browseable mirror (the code is from the [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org) project):
Surrounding [Header file](http://repo.or.cz/w/luajit-2.0.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/src/lj_obj.h) (or [whole project](http://repo.or.cz/w/luajit-2.0.git/)).

Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: "I'm fairly certain that the original author knew what he was doing" never assume that.

Comment: Don't be so distrustful... Some people have earned the right to be believed until proven wrong ;) (this is from a JIT-compiler codebase, a one-man project, and currently the fastest one for any dynamic language that I know of, so...)

Comment: Specific knowledge of bit patterns of floating point numbers.  Read about [Quake's InvSqrt](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/) for more brain-wrinkling code like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

num2bit is designed to implement the [Lua BitOp semantics](http://bitop.luajit.org/semantics.html) especially wrt. modular arithmetic. The implementation-defined behavior is well under control, since LuaJIT only works for specific CPUs, platforms and compilers, anyway. Don't use this code anywhere else.

num2u64 is a workaround for a bug/misfeature of MSVC where it always converts double to uint64_t via int64_t. This doesn't give the desired results for numbers >= 2^63. MS considers this abomination a 'feature'. Duh.

Answer (score 3):

num2bit: By setting the 51st and 52nd bit to 1, this forces the exponent to be a specific number (otherwise there would be overflow) - then when you return (int32_t)o.u32.lo you know you are getting an integer back with the same value as the 'low 32 bits' of the double since the exponent is fixed. So, this is a trick to get the integer value of most doubles quickly. It looks like it would truncate off numbers after the decimal point by doing this, and it would have unexpected effects if it was 2^51 or larger to begin with.

```
>>> math.frexp(1.0 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.7500000000000001, 53)
>>> math.frexp(0.0 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.75, 53)
>>> math.frexp(564563465 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.7500000626791358, 53)
>>> math.frexp(-564563465 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.7499999373208642, 53)
>>> math.frexp(1.5 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.7500000000000002, 53)
>>> math.frexp(1.6 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.7500000000000002, 53)
>>> math.frexp(1.4 + 6755399441055744.0)
(0.7500000000000001, 53)
```

EDIT: The reason why both the 51st and 52nd bit are set is because if you only set the 52nd bit, then negative numbers would cause the exponent to change:

```
>>> math.frexp(0 + 4503599627370496.0)
(0.5, 53)
>>> math.frexp(-543635634 + 4503599627370496.0)
(0.9999998792886404, 52)
```

num2u64: No clue. But the first number is 2^63 and the second is 2^64. It's probably to prevent overflow or signedness failure when casting a double larger than 2^63 to its integer representation, but I can't tell you more.

Comment: tl;dr: It's a fancy way of bit-shifting the bits in the `double` so the one's place is the last bit, and simultaneously converting from sign-magnitude to two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

`num2bit` manually converts the in-memory representation of a IEEE standard `double` to 32-bit, fixed-point, two's complement signed format, using rounding to the nearest integer.

Converting through a `union` is unsafe because it violates *strict type aliasing rules*. You're not allowed to write to one member of a union, then read from another. It would be more proper to do something like

```
static int32_t num2bit(double n)
{
  int32_t o;
  n += 6755399441055744.0;  /* 2^52 + 2^51 */
  memcpy( & o, & n, sizeof o ); /* OK with strict aliasing but must mind endianness. */
  return o;
}
```

This function is probably intended as an optimization, but its value as such is dubious. You need to re-test on every new microprocessor and ensure it's only used on hardware where it's faster.

Note also that a plain C floating-integral conversion uses round-to-zero, or truncation. This function is perhaps not intended to handle fractional values at all.

---

`num2u64` is a Windows-specific workaround (note the `#ifdef`). When converting a `double` value greater than 2<sup>63</sup> to an unsigned integer, "something bad" happens (perhaps saturation), so the author subtracts 2<sup>64</sup> to make it a negative number, then casts that to a signed, negative integer, then casts the result to an unsigned integer which will have a value greater than 2<sup>63</sup>.

In any case, you can tell the intent is simply to convert a `double` to a `uint64_t`, since that's all it does on non-Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

These functions "work" by magic.

This comes from §6.2.6.1p7 of n1570.pdf, which is the C standard draft: When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values

Note how the code presented uses *unspecified values* by assigning to o.n and then using the value of o.u32.lo.

This comes from §6.3.1.3p3 of n1570.pdf, which is the C standard draft: Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Note how the code presented invokes implementation-defined behaviour, as it converts from unsigned to signed 32-bit integer multiple times. Suppose that it were to instead raise an implementation-defined computational exception signal. If the default signal handler were to return, this would also result in undefined behaviour. `/* They think it's a feature. */`

Comment: look at footnote 95: "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be a trap representation."

Comment: Using a trap representation is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `uint32_t` *cannot* have any trap representations (7.20.1.1 p2: "The typedef name uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N and no padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.")

Comment: Very well. I'll modify my post.

Comment: You're talking about type aliasing, which is something the author probably took for granted. The "they think it's a feature" thing probably relates to floating-point conversion, not integer overflow exceptions which will never occur on Windows.

Comment: This answer was unhelpful. As I stated in my question, I'm trying to find out how the code _works_, not if the latest C standard makes any assertions about it's behavior (full C??-compliance is a ridiculous notion for a JIT compiler, since such a program, by nature, needs to be architecture specific/to access functionality not covered by the C-standard in order to be efficient).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Since when was C designed for Windows? Do you have the ability to predict the future? Suppose I were to develop an implementation of C that runs in Windows, and causes an exception to be raised when an unsigned-to-signed conversion results in a value that can't be represented in the new type. What now, huh?

radioflash: Don't blame me for your inability to ask specific questions.

Let us consider the historic need for a C standard. The C standard provides infinite guarantees regarding portability on all systems that implement C today *and in the unimaginably distant future*.

Comment: @radioflash `#ifdef _MSC_VER` is a check for Microsoft's compiler, and that's simply something they would never do. Yes, that's within my capabilities of prognostication.